# Why YouTube shows two different names?

Tags: youtube, google-account, account-management

I created my channel with the name of 'enthusiastic ladka' and everywhere it shows expect my YouTube main title name. Why it is different?

Here is the screenshot of my problem.

[image]

Comment: probably due to google+ did you try to change your name there?

Answer (score 0):

- go to **https://aboutme.google.com/u/0/#name**
- click on that pen icon and change your name:

[image]

[image]